# Is it possible to paste two line breaks in question/answer?

Tags: support, markdown

Is it possible to paste two line breaks(better separation of paragraphs) in question/answer? I know how I can paste a line break (***for line break add 2 spaces at end***), but if I repeat it, then only one line break is shown.

```
code
```

**For bold text** after code section I find two line breaks as separator better.

---

Trying the answer with `&nbsp;`:

Works!

Trying the answer with `<br/>`:

  
Works too!

Comment: As you see from the answers, it is easy to demonstrate markdown as code. I'm not the downvoter, but maybe that kind of unclarity is the reason.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I haven't known how to paste two line breaks and even if I use a code field what should I write there? Two lines with two spaces at end, which will be as a single line shown? It is already in my question..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can it be, that somebody down voted, because somebody has deleted "Thank you" from my question? ;))

Comment: No, that's unlikely. "Thank you" is _irrelevant fluff_, and that's the reason why I removed it. I don't believe that could be the reason for a down vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use raw HTML, which for line break is `<br />` tag:

Line 1
Line 2

Line 3

Markdown:

```
Line 1  
Line 2
<br /><br />
Line 3
```

Comment: Booo, your solution is less typing ...:(

Comment: Luv this solution more than rene's

Comment: @rene And imho easier to remember ;)

Comment: @rene Even less typing if you leave out the slash character (`/`) which is totally fine since SE uses the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: @KodosJohnson ... but it shows where ShadowWizard and myself come from .. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `&nbsp;` on a line with 2 spaces at the end to force a new line

```
code
```

**bold text**

Markup:

> ```
>    code
>
> &nbsp;  
> &nbsp;  
> **bold text**
> ```